# Wordpress javascript conflict template and calendar

Tags: javascript

Wordpress javascript conflict template and calendar Wordpress javascript conflict template and calendar This error throws me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.js:2
     v.extend.each jquery.js:2
     e.widget jquery.ui.widget.min.js:5
     (anonymous function) jquery.ui.tabs.min.js:5
     (anonymous function) jquery.ui.tabs.min.js:5
```

Comment: Please form this into a question.

Comment: I have answered this generically, but I am fairly certain the question is [*off-topic*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here. Voting to put on hold - it can be reopened after a clarifying edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of an identifier that has never been declared (i.e. is not a valid variable).
A construct along the lines of the following would remedy that issue:

Option 1:

```
if (typeof yourVariable !== "undefined") {
    var theLength = yourVariable.length;
} else {
    var theLength = 0;
}
```

Option 2:

```
var yourVariable = [];
if ( /* some condition */ ) {
    // reassign yourVariable;
}
var theLength = yourVariable.length;
```

My guess would be, that, as of now, your code looks like option two, without the first line, meaning that you declare the variable inside a conditional and check its length outside the conditional regardless of whether it was met.
But that's just a guess.

Comment: Dont word look  this
TypeError: e is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

...eturn t?u.length:u?nt.error(e):L(e,a).slice(0)}function at(e,t,r){var i=t.dir,s=...

Comment: @Clips Sorry mate, but your "question" was hardly understandable. I can't make nothing of that comment. Sorry again, but that's a random assembly of words without coherence.